# Could cabal warn about unused package in dependencies?

Tags: haskell, cabal

For given cabal project how could unused dependencies packages be retrieved?

Is there a way to get something like warning during `cabal install` process if there is a package mentioned in project dependency and there is no any usage of it, so it could be removed from dependencies?

Comment: I don't think `cabal` is prepared for that yet. It would certainly be a useful feature.

Comment: It'd be useful, but it's an engineering challenge right now. It straddles the line between what cabal knows (packages listed in the .cabal file) and what GHC knows (what packages are used). It might not be bad to add it as a standalone utility, but it's probably not practical to include it with by default with `cabal install`.

Comment: If you had an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/15203191/812053 , the rest would be relatively straightforward...

Answer (score 8):

I think the program [packunused](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/packunused) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8):

There are some options:

- For GHC 8.6 and earlier, [Weeder version 1 by Neil Mitchell](https://github.com/ndmitchell/weeder) can find unused dependencies.
- For GHC 8.10 and later, [there is a warning GHC may emit](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.10.4/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html#ghc-flag--Wunused-packages) (with the GHC option `-Wunused-packages`) when it sees unnecessary packages in the package database. Since Cabal prepares the package database, any unnecessary package is an unused dependency.

Unfortunately, GHC 8.8 is left out.

**P. S.**   There was recently released a program called [`prune-juice`](https://github.com/dfithian/prune-juice) that should work for GHC 8.8 too.

Answer (score 2):

[cabal-progdeps](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-progdeps) lists dependencies once the cabal project has been built.

You can check if thay are all used by adding an unused one to your project.

It requires the same Cabal library version used in cabal-install, otherwise it gives errors parsing dist/setup-config.

Comment: I am sorry, I have checked cabal-progdeps and it lists all dependencies in the .cabal project file, wether used or not, so it is not a good tool to find out the unused ones.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't help at all :[

Comment: by the way, `cabal-progdeps` package is kinda outdated because of upper boundaries for `filepath` and `directory`

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ You can always do it manually. From a working project cabal file, comment out one suspected unused dependency and try to cabal configure and build it.

Comment: Yep, question is about this process automation.

Answer (score 1):

There is yet another tool:

https://github.com/ndmitchell/weeder
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/weeder

It's not yet on Stackage though